# Dag dependency Plug in : error : cannot import name 'conf' from 'airflow'

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We are trying to implement the dag dependency plug in by using below git hub as reference

```
https://github.com/ms32035/airflow-dag-dependencies
```

But we are facing an error :

```
**cannot import name 'conf' from 'airflow'**
```

tried checking the below page but didn't helped

```
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/upgrade/rules/fix_conf_not_importable_from_airflow.py
```

Currently we are in Airflow 2.0. any one please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend upgrading to Airflow 2.1, the DAG Dependency view was added to core Airflow itself by the author of https://github.com/ms32035/airflow-dag-dependencies in https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/13199 which was released in Airflow 2.1 as shown in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Kaxil. Could you pls suggest if there is any document we can follow/refer to update/upgrade to Airflow 2.1

Comment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/5d90bcb93a4318de7db7fd5527bb45c823fb0dab/UPDATING.md#airflow-210 should show you the details of any breaking changes. From Airflow > 2.0 we follow strict SemVer so we won't have any breaking changes in minor or patch release, so the upgrade should be straightforward ideally

Comment: TIL kaxil :) Thanks, I missed this one :)

Comment: @kaxil .. We have upgraded to 2.1.3 version and now we can see Dependencies plugin is added but it was not showing anything and the page is complete blank. Do we need to enable anyware

Comment: @kaxil any suggestion pls

Comment: No, nothing else should be needed. Maybe you are hitting this bug: https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16610 which is fixed by https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/17990/ . Unfortunately this will be part of 2.2.0 that hasn't been released yet but will be released soon (in about 2 weeks around 1-2 weeks of Oct 2021). But you can try that patch out.

Comment: You can test it out with 2.2.0b2 in a DEV environment: https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/2.2.0b2/

Answer (score 2):

Did you actually change:

`from airflow import conf`

to:

`from airflow.configuration import conf`

As suggested in the upgrade check you referred to?

https://github.com/ms32035/airflow-dag-dependencies/blob/master/dag-dependencies-plugin/dag_dependencies_plugin.py#L4

I think it should help